# Why isn't Android Beam/NFC receiving the records that I send?

Tags: android, nfc, ndef, nfc-p2p, android-beam

I've read the documentation a few times now and looked at the example code but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Whenever I put my two devices together I see the Beam screen and tap it, but nothing seems to be sent and none of my breakpoints get hit.
Here's my code, please help me figure out why nothing is sent to the other device. In the editor I can see that everything in `BeamFileActivity`is run, I just never see any of the break points in `MainActivity` get accessed on the receiving device. What am I doing wrong?

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.myapp">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />
    <application
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="QUERY_LOG"
            android:value="false" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME"
            android:value="com.myapp.domain" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.DRIVE_OPEN" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.DRIVE_SAVE" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk.111111111" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:scheme="vnd.android.nfc"
                    android:host="ext"
                    android:pathPrefix="/com.myapp:SpreadsheetDom"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".dialog.BeamFileActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_beam_file"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.myapp.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>
```

MainActivity: This is what will receive the Beam intent, I'm only including the methods I think are relevant.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    //I removed some code that reloads my application, didn't seem relevant

    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
        processIntent(getIntent());
    }
}

/**
 * Parses the NDEF Message from the intent and stores the collection
 */
void processIntent(Intent intent) {

    Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
    // only one message expected during the beam
    NdefMessage msg = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[0];

    //This is the data I'm beaming, It has a method that converts its data to a byte array, and a method, fromBytes() that converts bytes into the object
    SpreadsheetDom dom = new SpreadsheetDom();
    try {

        for(int i = 0; i < msg.getRecords().length; i++) {

            if(SpreadsheetDom.class.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(new String(msg.getRecords()[i].getType()))) {

                dom.fromBytes(msg.getRecords()[i].getPayload());
                //removed some code that saves and displays changes
            }
        }
    } catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {

    }
}

@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

    setIntent(intent);
}
```

BeamFileActivity: This is a separate activity that just displays instructions for beaming the data and does the actual beam.

```
private void initFileToBeam(Long spreadsheetId) {

    try {

        List<SpreadsheetDom> spreadsheets = db.getSpreadsheetDao().queryForEq(SpreadsheetDom.SPREADSHEET_ID_NAME, spreadsheetId);
        if(spreadsheets != null && spreadsheets.size() > 0) {

            fileToBeam = spreadsheets.get(0);
        }
    } catch(SQLException e) {

        ErrorDialog ed = new ErrorDialog(this, "Unable to beam current collection.");
        ed.show();
    }
}

@Override
public NdefMessage createNdefMessage(NfcEvent event) {

    if(fileToBeam == null) {

        Long spreadsheetId = Settings.getInstance().get(SettingKey.CURRENT_SPREADSHEET).getValue();
        initFileToBeam(spreadsheetId);
    }

    NdefMessage msg = null;
    try {

        msg = new NdefMessage(
                new NdefRecord[]{
                        new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_EXTERNAL_TYPE, "application/com.myapp:SpreadsheetDom".getBytes(), new byte[0], fileToBeam.toBytes()),
                        //NdefRecord.createExternal("com.myapp", "spreadsheetdom", fileToBeam.toBytes()),
                        NdefRecord.createApplicationRecord("com.myapp")
                });
    } catch(IOException e) {

        String textMessage = "Unable to transfer collection: " + e.getMessage();
        msg = new NdefMessage(
                new NdefRecord[]{
                        NdefRecord.createMime("text/plain", textMessage.getBytes()),
                        NdefRecord.createApplicationRecord("com.myapp")
                });
    }

    return msg;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    Intent exportFileIntent = getIntent();
    Long spreadsheetId = exportFileIntent.getLongExtra(Constants.EXTRA_SPREADSHEET_ID, Database.INVALID_ID);

    initFileToBeam(spreadsheetId);

    mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    if (mNfcAdapter == null) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "NFC is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
        return;
    }
    // Register callback
    mNfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback(this, this);
}
```

Really all of this is from the examples and documentation [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/2f33e1eae0671cc1aa3d367f8d900b532f6ca80f/samples/AndroidBeamDemo/src/com/example/android/beam/Beam.java), [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html) and [here](https://developer.android.com/training/beam-files/send-files.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sending a different NDEF record than what your `MainActivity` expects. Your `MainActivity` is registered for the NFC Forum external type "com.myapp:SpreadsheetDom":

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:scheme="vnd.android.nfc"
          android:host="ext"
          android:pathPrefix="/com.myapp:SpreadsheetDom"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Since intent filters in Android are case-*sensitive* but NFC Forum external type names are case-*insensitive*, Android automatically converts the names of NFC Forum external types (just as with MIME types) to *lower*-case. As your intent filter contains the upper-case letters "S" and "D", it will never match the type name of your NFC Forum external type. Therefore, you have to specify the type name as all lower-case to achieve a match (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23036024/2425802)):

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:scheme="vnd.android.nfc"
          android:host="ext"
          android:pathPrefix="/com.myapp:spreadsheetdom"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Next, in your `BeamFileActivity` you create an external record with the invalid type name "application/com.myapp:SpreadsheetDom":

```
msg = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] {
        new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_EXTERNAL_TYPE, "application/com.myapp:SpreadsheetDom".getBytes(), new byte[0], fileToBeam.toBytes()),
        NdefRecord.createApplicationRecord("com.myapp")
});
```

An NFC Forum external type name that matches the above intent filter would be "com.myapp:spreadsheetdom" (again, all lower-case letters). You can create such a record with (make sure to use US-ASCII encoding for the type name):

```
msg = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] {
        new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_EXTERNAL_TYPE, "com.myapp:spreadsheetdom".getBytes("US-ASCII"), new byte[0], fileToBeam.toBytes()),
        NdefRecord.createApplicationRecord("com.myapp")
});
```

Finally, note that "com.myapp" is not a well-formed domain name for an external type according to the NFC Forum Record Type Definition. Instead, a well-formed domain name would be "myapp.com" (Internet domain name format instead of Java package name format).

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and it's still not working. I switched to a simple text message and changed the type to TNF_MIME_MEDIA and I was able to get data to transfer. However when I switched back to my spreadsheetdom it stopped working and it seems the problem might be the size. I convert the spreadsheetdom to a bytearrayoutputstream and it fills 9 buffers in that object. I don't know if that's a lot or not, seems like a lot. Is there a limit on the amount of data you can send with a TNF_MIME_MEDIA message?

Comment: @Hardy How big (in bytes) is your data blob? Does the external type work with the simple text message?

Comment: When I try the external type it always goes to the play store and never opens my app. The byteArrayOutputStream.size() reports 322,000

Comment: @Hardy Regarding the external type and going to Play Store: Are you using the same AAR (`NdefRecord.createApplicationRecord("com.myapp")`) for the external type and for the MIME type/simple text message? The device going to Play Store suggests that you are using a wrong package name in the AAR.

Comment: @Hardy Regarding the size: That's definitely a lot. NFC is intended for small amounts of data. With that data size you will certainly run into various issues, such as that you have to keep the devices together and connected for a *very long* time. Also, I'm not sure if Beam has any timeout/size limitations that would make the that transfer even impossible. You would be better off to try the file transfer mechanism of Android Beam. That would only establish communication over NFC and tranfer the actual data over an out-of-band channel. See https://developer.android.com/training/beam-files/

Comment: I am using the same AAR. I've checked and double checked the package name and it's correct. Unless I should be doing more than the base package name. Should it include the class name of the receiving class? I'll look into beaming files, I was trying to avoid that since the data I want to beam is coming from a database but I suppose I could write it out as a file and then send the file.

Comment: @Hardy First, please don't edit other people's answers. If you have a different answer that fits for you, post it as your own answer (feel free to accept your own answer then). Second, what you edited into my post is simply wrong: Obviously, if you use the external type name "com.myapp:externalType" your app will **never** open for that record (exept for a very small set of Android versions). You simply must not use upper-case letters in an external type name.

Comment: Sorry. First, I edited your answer because I wanted you to get credit for helping me. Second, setting the type to externalType is what worked, setting it to spreadsheetdom didn't work. Here is the doc that indicates externalType is correct: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html scroll down to the section titled TNF_EXTERNAL_TYPE

Comment: @Hardy I'm well aware of that, unfotunately, wrong and misleading part of the Android documentation (this seems to be a problem with many parts of the Android NFC documentation). These pices of documentation seem to come from a time where the Android NFC API was still under heavy development and haven't been updated since.

Comment: I thought I would double check everything we've talked about and when I did everything worked. So I don't know what I was doing wrong before but what you suggest above works for me now. The only difference between what I had after first reading your answer and what I have right now is that I compress the byte array. Perhaps something was timing out before that isn't with the compression in place? IDK. Again, thank you for your help.